# Why is my echo variable not displaying upon submission?

Tags: php

I am working on a school project for php I have 2 files, checkBlank.php and form.php. everything displays correctly and its submitting the form well, but its not displaying the echo $message for fields that were not filled in.

Here is the code:

```
if(isset($_POST['submitted']) and $_POST['submitted'] == 'yes') {
    foreach($_POST as $field => $value) {
        if(empty($value)) {
            $blank_array[] = $field;
        }

        else {
            $good_data[$field] = strip_tags(trim($value));
        }
    }

    if(@sizeof($blank_array) > 0) { 
        $message = "<p style ='color: red; margin-bottom: 0; font-weight: bold'>

                                        You have not filled in all the fields.
                                        Please fill in the:

                        <ul style='color: red; margin-top: 0; list-style: none' >";

            foreach($blank_array as $value) {
                $message .= "<li>$value</li>";
            }
            $message .= "</ul>";

            echo $message;

            extract($good_data);
            include ("form.inc");
            exit();

    }
    echo "All fields contain information";
}

else {
    include("form.inc");
}
```

Comment: Wow, that's a new one for me @Barmar. I've never used it or seen it used.

Comment: You can try var_dump($message)

Comment: Is it displaying "All fields contain information" instead?

Comment: Try using `var_dump($blank_array)` to see if that's being set properly.

Comment: its not displaying any echos, it just redisplays the form and doesn't keep the good info either.  Where do I put the var_dump in the code?